# React Native Picker Select: How to get no placeholder?

Tags: react-native, react-native-picker-select

I've tried to do `placeholder={{}}` but then the first item label became the placeholder.

What can I do when I just want to literally have NO PLACEHOLDER at all?

```
<RNPickerSelect
  placeholder={{}}
  onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
  items={[
   { label: 'Football', value: 'football' },
   { label: 'Baseball', value: 'baseball' },
   { label: 'Hockey', value: 'hockey' },
  ]}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
placeholder={{ }}
```

This work for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this, but there still have a blank select at the list, and I set the value to `default` that you could use it to distinguish.

```js
<RNPickerSelect
  onValueChange={value => console.log(value)}
  items={[
    { label: "Football", value: "football" },
    { label: "Baseball", value: "baseball" },
    { label: "Hockey", value: "hockey" }
  ]}
  placeholder={{ label: " ", value: "default" }}  //here   OwO//
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

placeholder={' '}

**Inside string give space its 100% works for me**